# Pinch-to-zoom for components layered on top of React Native Camera

Tags: react-native, pinchzoom, react-native-camera

I've been using the [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) library to handle camera views in the app I'm building, and I've also been asked to add some shapes like rectangles, crosses and circles on top of it as a guide to help the user frame the image correctly. I implemented a component called `Frame` by combining some overlapping (`position: 'absolute'`) `View` components together, then I displayed it as a child of `RNCamera`, and now it covers most of the camera view, but the pinch-to-zoom feature (enabled through the `useNativeZoom` prop) doesn't work anymore on the covered area.

Moving `Frame` after `RNCamera` has the same final graphical result but doesn't seem to solve the issue. I also tried to tinker with the `pointerEvents` prop in `Frame`, but without success.

What's the best way to fix this? Should I somehow propagate events upwards so that they are processed by `RNCamera`? Or maybe there's a way to make `Frame` "invisible" to touch events, so to speak?

React Native version: `0.62.2`
React Native Camera version: `3.27.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the solution was rather simple and I probably missed it by pure chance: include `Frame` in `RNCamera`, and set `pointerEvents="none"` on the outermost frame `View`.
I also upgraded my RN version to `0.63.2`, but I don't think that played a role.